# Ocean 2012 missing class PetrelSystem

Tags: ocean, petrel

Question received on the Ocean portal:

I got following error. For all **PetrelSystem** declaration in my code, I got the same error. I added Ocean.Core dll file from new path(Petrel 2012), but that did not help:

The name 'PetrelSystem' does not exist in the current context

the code was copiling correctly on Ocean for Petrel 2011

Answer (score 4):

Static class **PetrelSystem** is defined in **Slb.Ocean.Petrel.Global.dll**, not in Core. Core is for non-Petrel stuff. Make sure you have all the libraries included.

There is a small difficulty in moving to 2012 in the fact that some classes that were previously defined in Slb.Ocean.Petrel.dll have been migrated to Slb.Ocean.Petrel.Global.dll